# How to select date from the calender using the datevalue in the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my html

```
<input type=text name="date" value=7/8/2019>
```

This is my date picker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
    autoclose: true, 
    endDate: '+0d',
    todayBtn: 'linked' 
});
```

I want to select the date in the calendar using the date value in the text box

Comment: What version of JQuery UI are you using?

Comment: If you edit this to add what you see currently, and what your expected result is you will get better answers.

It will also fix this question and help you to become un question banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input should look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="7/8/2019">
```

You need to wrap your attribute values in "" if they are not numeric.

Answer (score 1):

The code which you paste is call javascript not html

But you can use html input tag with type `date` or `datetime-local` like this, which give the additional attributes to set min, max etc.

```
<input name="submittion-date" 
       type="date" 
       max="2017-06-20" 
       min="2017-06-01" />
```

You can use jquery to read the value

for further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_value.asp

Comment: dude that was helpful but the code is not working in firefox and IE8